# Examples of applications of Beilinson-Bernstein localization?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, sheaf-theory, derived-categories, d-modules

I'm a sheaf theorist who knows a little representation theory but is not familiar with it. According to my memory, I was once told that one virtue of the [Beilinson-Bernstein localization theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Beilinson-Bernstein+localization) is that it breaks representations to D-modules and the later, being sheaves, enjoy the local-to-global principle. Thus, one can reduce difficult questions about representation theory to simpler questions about geometry which can then be studied locally.

My question is what is an example of such a strategy? Or more generally, what is an example of a question which is hard to study as a representation theory question but becomes more trackable when studied as a D-module question through this theorem?

Comment: It was used in the proof of the Jantzen conjectures: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jantzen_filtration

Comment: these are conjectures on filtrations of Verma modules, and the proof uses flag varieties and their geometry.

Comment: Citation: "It is shown that the localization functor sends the Jantzen filtration on standard Harish-Chandra modules to the weight filtration on the corresponding perverse sheaves. The fact implies, conjectured by Jantzen, the hereditary property of the Jantzen filtration, the socle and cosocle properties, and so on."  https://zbmath.org/?au=&ti=%22A+proof+of+Jantzen+conjectures&so=&la=&py=&ab=&rv=&an=&en=&cc=&ut=&sw=&br=&any=&dm=